# Mysql select month when month starts from 20

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

The requirements says that each month starts from the 20th. For instance, the first of July is 20th June. Now in my query is

```
select * from tbl where MONTH(mois)=7
```

But I know it's not correct, is there any way to do this?

my question is how to select rows of a certain month knowing that each month sarts from 20? is there a general sql solution that wouldn't be specific for a certain database?

Comment: You need to specify more information about your problem. This is only the requirement, not the goal.

Comment: What is your Question?

Comment: Date and time functions are usually specific for a certain database.

Comment: @VMai Ok, then i'll take the mysql solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In MySQL you could do that with a CASE construct:

```
SELECT
    CASE 
        WHEN DAYOFMONTH(mois) >= 20 THEN (MONTH(mois) + 1) % 12 
        ELSE MONTH(mois) 
    END current_month;
```

The [modulo operator](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/arithmetic-functions.html#operator_mod) % takes care that it works for the days between the 20th and 31th of december too. It will return then the january.

You could use it in your query like that:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE
    CASE 
        WHEN DAYOFMONTH(mois) >= 20 THEN (MONTH(mois) + 1) % 12 
        ELSE MONTH(mois) 
    END = 7;
```

**Note**

Current MySQL can't use an index for this where condition.

Answer (score 0):

I read the question like, if day >= 20 then you need to get next month Number , else the same month number.

**SQL**

```
DECLARE @DT DATE = '2014-12-19'

SELECT  CASE    WHEN (DATEPART(DAY,@DT))/20 = 1 
                THEN (DATEPART(MONTH,@DT) + 1)%12
                ELSE DATEPART(MONTH,@DT) 
        END

--SQL is in TSQL
```

**Result:**

12